# Can you setup LDAP / AD Authenticaton to a Postgres DB on AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

[AWS does not allow you to modify the pg_hba.conf file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Access) which is unfortunate to say the least. Does anyone know of a way that we can setup external user authentication for a RDS Postgres instance?

The driving factor of this is compliance due to the industry we are in. It requires being able to fully log who is querying what. We're trying to keep identity management as centralized as possible and would rather not have to manage a bunch of local users and permissions in postgres.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know of a way that we can setup external user
>   authentication for a RDS Postgres instance?

No, this is not possible.